# Negative x and y range

Tags: python, range

My problem is that the `generated_map` is not utilizing full negative range for x and y

```
def generate_map(x_range, y_range, locations):

    generated_map = []

    for x in range(locations):
        generated_map.append([random.randint(x_range, y_range), random.randint(x_range, y_range)])
        
    

    return generated_map

generated_map = generate_map(-300,300,35)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you expect `generated_map` to contain every single possible floating point number between `x_range` and `y_range`? Or what precisely do you mean by "not utilizing full (negative) range"?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan yes i mean that

Comment: Still unclear. You only have 35 iterations so you can't get all the integers between `-300` and `300`. Please explain the issue in detail. Perhaps add the expected and actual outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue with this was the `for` loop.

```
for x in range(locations):
        x_value = random.randint(-x_range, x_range)
        y_value = random.randint(-y_range, y_range)

        generated_map.append([x_value, y_value])
```